# Android/Java Rendering Problems - Couldn't Resolve Resource / Failed to Convert into Drawable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am received a rendering error in my Android Studio application. It says "Couldn't Resolve Resource" and later "Failed to Convert into Drawable." The details are as follows:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/breakfast_lto' must start with #
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:79)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:270)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:742)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor113.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:107)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:149)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The drawable is a .png image, but it appears to be reading it as a color value. What might be the issue.

The XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="midamcorp.com.burgerkingapp.breakfastHome"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_breakfast_home">
    <TextView android:text="Breakfast" android:id="@+id/headerText" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" android:textSize="48dp" android:textAlignment="center" android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

        <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/breakfast_lto" android:id="@+id/breakfastLTOButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/breakfastListContainer"
    ></ListView>







    <ImageButton android:background="@drawable/breakfast_standard" android:id="@+id/breakfastStandardButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewLunchButton"
        android:background="@drawable/lunch_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what the issue was - it is working now (even with android:background). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace 
`android:background="@drawable/breakfast_lto"`

with this

`android:src="@drawable/breakfast_lto" />`

Answer (score 2):

The **android:background** attribute is expecting a color.

Try using the **android:src** attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just close your project and restart it.I don't know why,but for my project,it can solve the problem.

Comment: Wish it did for mine. It doesn't. Also tried removing the underscore in the name. Same error. Already was all lower case in the name. Regardless, I get the same error. Same png works fine in Eclipse. Problem only shows up in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. my xml looked like this:

```
<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/transitmap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mypicture"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"/> // had to add color because of the error, but knocked opacity down to zero
```

For some reason I was still getting the error. Oddly enough, restarting Android Studio made the error go away with no additional code changes from me.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have mentioned restarting IDE has worked, but that didn’t work for me.

Instead, I found that I had to simply rename the image file so that it did NOT start with a number. All icons in the Android Developer Icon Pack start with a number, and I had just copied the one over. It appears that if the file starts with a number, it is assumed to be the start of a hexadecimal color value, and hence looks for the # symbol.

working with: Eclipse Juno 3.7.2, Android SDK 21.1 && Android Studio